# PostgreSQL trigger to Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-migration, database-trigger

I am trying to write a PostgreSQL trigger in Oracle and I get stuck with the syntax. Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_directori_ins_before_row()
     RETURNS TRIGGER AS $trg_directori_ins_before_row$

BEGIN

   UPDATE directori_teatru SET dataincetarefunctie=NEW.datanumirefunctie-1  WHERE idteatru=NEW.idteatru AND dataincetarefunctie is NULL;     RETURN NEW;


  END;   $trg_directori_ins_before_row$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  CREATE TRIGGER trg_directori_ins_before_row   BEFORE INSERT ON directori_teatru    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_directori_ins_before_row();
```

Can somebody, please, help me to write this in Oracle? Thank you very much!

Later edit:

There is a theatre with a manager and this trigger is for setting a new manager for that theatre.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_managers_ins_before_row()
     RETURNS TRIGGER AS $trg_managers_ins_before_row$

BEGIN

   UPDATE managers_theatre SET endjobdate=NEW.startdatejob-1
 WHERE idtheatre=NEW.idtheatre AND endjobdate is NULL; 
   RETURN NEW; 

  END;
  $trg_managers_ins_before_row$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  CREATE TRIGGER trg_managers_ins_before_row
  BEFORE INSERT ON managers_theatre 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_managers_ins_before_row();
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, and where does Oracle come in? Is `directori_teatru` a foreign table?

Comment: Oracle trigger syntax is rather different from PostgreSQL. However, it ought to be fairy easy to convert the code ... Except that the purpose of the original trigger is not clear. If it's supposed to be doing what I think  then that won't work in Oracle, because it will hurl a mutating table exception. There are workarounds. But please **edit your question** to explain what business rule your PostgreSQL trigger implements before anybody invests a large chunk of their time writing code which won't solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've edited my question in order to be more clear. managers_theatre is not a foreign table, is the table where I want to make the changes.

Comment: You are closing the end bound of a date range when you create a new record. So yes, you're going to run into the mutating table problem. Alas I don't have time to give you a solution now but there are plenty of questions on StackOverflow for `[oracle} mutating table`: try reading some of those threads. The solution you need is a COMPOUND trigger.

Comment: Thank you! The simply fact that I know now that I need a compound trigger it helps me.